# Ошибка requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema при парсинге

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Пишу код, который должен пройтись по всем ссылкам ru.wikipedia.org  Категория:Животные_по_алфавиту
([https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Категория:Животные_по_алфавиту&from=А](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83&from=%D0%90))
, но на сайте в ссылках меняются не цифры (.../page = 1..), а pagefrom=Азовская+пуголовка (ссылка зависит от первых животных на странице). Поэтому приходится идти более сложным путём

**Алгоритм кода следующий**:

1. Взять ссылку с кнопки # На сайте есть кнопка "Следующая страница".
2. Перейти по ссылке
3. Повторить
4. Остановиться на последней ссылке (сам её прописываю)

```
import  requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parser(url):
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    return soup

    
def parser_next_link():
    soup = parser(url)
    result_a = soup.find_all('a',{'title':'Категория:Животные по алфавиту'})
    for i in result_a:
        if i.get_text() == 'Следующая страница':
            link = 'ru.wikipedia.org/' + i.get('href')
            # Нам нужна, только первая ссылка т.к. вторая её дублирует
            break
    return link


wiki_link = ['https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Категория:Животные_по_алфавиту&subcatfrom=0&filefrom=0&pageuntil=Азовская+пуголовка#mw-pages']

for i in wiki_link:
    url = i 
    wiki_link.append(parser_next_link())
    # Последняя страница 
    if url == 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Категория:Животные_по_алфавиту&pagefrom=Zabrus&subcatfrom=0&filefrom=0#mw-pages':
        break
```

Выводит:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Project_Py\test_2.py", line 26, in <module>
    wiki_link.append(parser_next_link())
  File "c:\Project_Py\test_2.py", line 12, in parser_next_link
    soup = parser(url)
  File "c:\Project_Py\test_2.py", line 6, in parser
    html = requests.get(url).text
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 649, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 742, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'ru.wikipedia.org//w/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83&pagefrom=%D0%90%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&subcatfrom=%D0%90&filefrom=%D0%90#mw-pages'
PS C:\Project_Py> & C:/Users/Владелец/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0/python.exe c:/Project_Py/test_2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Project_Py\test_2.py", line 26, in <module>        
    wiki_link.append(parser_next_link())
  File "c:\Project_Py\test_2.py", line 12, in parser_next_link
    soup = parser(url)
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 649, in sendbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 649, in send                                                                      bz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 742, in get_adapter
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_q.org//w/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8bz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", lD0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&subcatfrom=%D0%90&filefine 742, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))     
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'ru.wikipedia.org//w/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83&pagefrom=%D0%90%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&subcatfrom=%D0%90&filefrom=%D0%90#mw-pages'
```

Понял, что ошибка в рекурсии, но у меня же есть условие, по которому  for останавливается.

Comment: Добавьте протокол (https) перед ru.wikipedia.org: `link = 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/' + i.get('href')`

Comment: Да, спасибо, но он переход и когда два слеша.

Comment: Поставил, жду ответа программы

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка `requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema` при запросе через `requests` в данном случае возникает из-за того, что в url не указан протокол (например http или https). Просто добавьте протокол в начало адреса:

```
link = 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/' + i.get('href')
```

Comment: Блиг теперь , это выводит: 
``` Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\Project_Py\test_2.py", line 28, in <module>

    wiki_link.append(parser_next_link())

  File "c:\Project_Py\test_2.py", line 19, in parser_next_link

    return link

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'link' referenced before assignment


PS C:\Project_Py> ```

Comment: Значит вы ничего не записали в переменную, а уже что-то пытаетесь из нее прочитать.

Comment: Но когда дело доводит до последней ссылки,
 if url == 'https://ru.wikipedia.org//w/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83&subcatfrom=0&filefrom=0&pagefrom=Zyras#mw-pages':
        break

Comment: (https в комменте удаляется автоматически)

Comment: Что "когда дело доводит до последней ссылки"?

Comment: когда доходит до последней ссылки

Comment: я её использую , чтобы из цикла выйти

Comment: И что? Вопрос в чем?

Comment: как исправить ошибку, всё хорошо, но ,как я понял программа не останавливается на if

Comment: Значит url не совпадает с тем, с которым вы сравниваете. Добавьте print(url) в цикл, и посмотрите что там выводится

Comment: Я так и сделал, прямо оттуда и скопировал

Comment: Ладно, спасибо ,сам  поищу где дыра

Comment: Ну вообще там url в кодированном виде приходит, типа `https://ru.wikipedia.org//w/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83&subcatfrom=0&filefrom=0&pagefrom=%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%8B#mw-pages`

Comment: Так что у вас условие так никогда не выполнится

Comment: Нужно url декодировать, например как в этом ответе показано: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16566128/4752653

Comment: Большое спасибо!